# Как правильно выводить контент товаров в интернет магазине?

Tags: laravel, reactjs

Как правильно выводить контент товаров в интернет магазине?
    backend Laravel,
    front React/Redux

для всех товаров создал роут

```
//   http/Controllers/Api/ProductsController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Products;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Products::all();
        return response()->json($products);
    }
}



//  routes/api.php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::resource('products', 'Api\ProductsController');



// actions/product.js
import { FETCH_PRODUCTS, FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS } from './types';

export function fetchProducts(){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: FETCH_PRODUCTS});

        axios.get(`/api/products`)
                .then(response =>{
                    dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response));
                })
    }
}

export function fetchProductsSuccess(products){
    return {
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
        payload: products
    };
}
```

есть страница ВСЕХ товаров а также на отдельной странице выводятся товары из категории РЕКОМЕНДОВАННЫЕ

Как правильно выводить Рекомендованные?
Создавать для них отдельный роут или получать в компоненте `<Recommended/>`
все товары и через фильтр по признаку выводить только рекомендованные?

Comment: всё в одном контроллере в одном методе по одном роуту. Фильтрация товаров, рекомендованные и другое - это всё сюда.

Comment: Спасибо. Куда сюда?

Comment: в этот один контроллер. Это если вы следуете CRUD. Если вы запрашиваете коллекцию у одной сущности (коллекцию продуктов у сущности Продукт), то это относится к index. Фильтрация тоже возвращает коллекцию. Значит всё это в один метод.